# OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use, Comes up only when running on a port forwarded connection

Tags: python, networking, multiplayer

I am trying to create a multiplayer server and have successfully made it work when using it on the same computer and the same local WiFi. However, when I try and move it to my server (on AWS) I get a new error.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "server.py", line 57, in lobby_port_connect
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

My code creates a "lobby" server which the client connects to send its username. Then the server quickly sends an open port to the client and disconnects opening up a connection on that port. The client then moves on and connects to that port leaving the other open for other connections. However, when recreating the lobby, the lobby server crashes, not allowing other clients to join but still holding the single client connection.

I am new to networking, so I don't know if there is a better way, but I have been stuck on this issue for a while.

Server Code:

```
# Bucket - refers to large pool of data
# KEY - Dictionary Key
# INDEX - Index in a list
# usr - user (player)
# Client - the user that is connected to a thread
# NOTIF - notify / notification

import socket
import threading
import json
import time
import sys
print("starting server")

global client_connections_data
client_connections_data = {} #[port, usrname, excpeted_ip, [{<Player ID>: [Value ID to change]},[last seen data]]]
global client_connections_threads
client_connections_threads = {} #will have threads insIDe
global client_data
client_data = {}# {<Client ID> : [Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, Screen_X, Screen_Y, Screen_Zoom, Selected_Tile_ID]}
global client_update_bucket #Bucket contains all cached data to be sent to any client
client_update_bucket = {}
global client_bucket_ID # A free client bucket to use
client_bucket_ID = 0
global player_count
player_count = 0
global message_ID
message_ID = 0

global HOST
global PORT
HOST = ""  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 60000  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
print(HOST)
def byte_decode(message):
    message = str(message)
    return (message[2:][:len(message)-3])

def lobby_port_connect():
    global client_connections_data
    global client_connections_threads
    global player_count
    free_port = 60001
    next_client_ID = 0
    while True:
        while True:
            port_taken = False
            for x in range(len(list(client_connections_data))):
                if client_connections_data[list(client_connections_data)[x]][0] == free_port:
                    port_taken = True
                    free_port += 1
                    break
            if port_taken == False:
                break
        print("Open to connect on free port: " + str(free_port))
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print(f"Lobby connection recived by {addr}")
            try:
                usrname = byte_decode(conn.recv(1024))
                print("Connection usrname:",usrname)
                if not usrname:
                    conn.close()
                conn.sendall(free_port.to_bytes(2, 'little', signed=False))
                for SEL_usr_join_NOTIF in client_connections_data: # Notifies all users that a new client has joined
                    client_connections_data[SEL_usr_join_NOTIF][3][1].append(["J", usrname, next_client_ID]) # J is for join
                client_connections_data[next_client_ID] = [free_port,usrname,addr,[{},[]]]
                print("Sent port:", free_port, "as bytes:",free_port.to_bytes(2, 'little', signed=False))
                client_connections_threads[next_client_ID] = threading.Thread(target=client_port_connect, args=(free_port,next_client_ID,usrname,))
                client_connections_threads[next_client_ID].start()
                next_client_ID += 1
                player_count += 1
            except:
                print(f"Client disconnected from lobby server.")
        conn.close()
        print("Connection done going to the next one")
        print()

def client_port_connect(port, client_ID, name):
    global client_connections_data
    global client_overwrite_bucket
    global bucket_overwrite_ID
    global client_update_bucket
    global bucket_append_ID
    global player_count
    global message_ID
    print("starting client connection port:",port)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(10)
    s.bind((HOST, port))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr} excpected usr ID:",client_ID)
        try:
            conn.send(bytes(json.dumps([client_data, client_ID]),encoding="utf-8"))
            print("Sent catching up data")
            client_data[client_ID] = [0, 0, 0 ,0 ,1 ,0] #[Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, Screen_X, Screen_Y, Screen_Zoom, Selected_Tile_ID]
            while True:
                #data = [{Client_Data}, push things] client data = {
                data = json.loads(byte_decode(conn.recv(1024)))
                if not data:
                    break
                for client_data_INDEX in data[0]: # The index for which the client data is stored in the list
                    client_data_INDEX = int(client_data_INDEX)
                    client_data[client_ID][client_data_INDEX] = data[0][str(client_data_INDEX)] #updating client
                    for SEL_usr_update_req_KEY in client_connections_data: #goes through all connected client data to request a change push
                        if SEL_usr_update_req_KEY != client_ID: #adds the bucket
                            if client_connections_data[SEL_usr_update_req_KEY][3][0].get(client_ID) == None: #Dictionary adding to a list
                                client_connections_data[SEL_usr_update_req_KEY][3][0][client_ID] = [client_data_INDEX]
                            elif not client_data_INDEX in client_connections_data[SEL_usr_update_req_KEY][3][0][client_ID]: #checks if the request is already there
                                client_connections_data[SEL_usr_update_req_KEY][3][0][client_ID].append(client_data_INDEX)
                client_data_uptdate = {}
                for data_sending_client_ID in client_connections_data[client_ID][3][0]: #Finds the ID of the other usrs that the client needs to be updated on
                    client_data_uptdate[data_sending_client_ID] = {}
                    for data_sending_item_INDEX in client_connections_data[client_ID][3][0][data_sending_client_ID]: #Updates every bit of new data
                        client_data_uptdate[data_sending_client_ID][data_sending_item_INDEX] = client_data[data_sending_client_ID][data_sending_item_INDEX]
                NOTIF_uptdate = []
                for NOTIF in client_connections_data[client_ID][3][1]: #goes through all notifications
                    if NOTIF[0] == "J": # Player joins
                        NOTIF_uptdate.append(NOTIF)
                    if NOTIF[0] == "D": # Player disconnects
                        NOTIF_uptdate.append(NOTIF)
                    client_connections_data[client_ID][3][1] = []
                client_connections_data[client_ID][3][0] = {}
                conn.send(bytes(json.dumps([client_data_uptdate,NOTIF_uptdate,message_ID]),encoding="utf-8"))
                message_ID += 1
        except Exception as e:
            e = str(e)
            print(e)
            if e == "[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host":
                for SEL_usr_join_NOTIF in client_connections_data: # Notifies all users that a new client has joined
                    client_connections_data[SEL_usr_join_NOTIF][3][1].append(["D", name, client_ID,]) # J is for join
                    print(f"{name}#{client_ID} disconnected")
            else:
                for SEL_usr_join_NOTIF in client_connections_data: # Notifies all users that a new client has joined
                    client_connections_data[SEL_usr_join_NOTIF][3][1].append(["E", name, client_ID, str(e)]) # J is for join
                    exception_type, exception_object, exception_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                    print(exception_type)
                    print(exception_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)
                    print(exception_traceback.tb_lineno)
            del client_data[client_ID]
            del client_connections_data[client_ID]
            print(client_connections_data)
            player_count -= 1
            conn.close()

lobby_connection_thread = threading.Thread(target=lobby_port_connect)
lobby_connection_thread.start()

while True:
    for x in range(10):
        time.sleep(3)
        if x == 10:
            if player_count == 0:
                client_update_bucket = {}
                message_ID = 0
                client_bucket_ID = 0
            else:
                print("trimming bucket")
                deleting_IDs = []
                for checking_append_bucket_item in client_update_bucket:
                    if client_update_bucket[checking_append_bucket_item][2] < 1:
                        deleting_IDs.append(checking_append_bucket_item)
                for del_ID in deleting_IDs:
                    del client_update_bucket[del_ID]
```

Client Code:

```
import socket
import json
import threading
import time
import random

global free_port
global HOST
global delay
global sever_sending_data
global client_ID
message_ID = -1
sever_sending_data = [{},[]]
other_usr_data = {}

HOST = input("IP: ")  # The server's hostname or IP address
usrname = input("username: ")
delay = int(input("delay: "))


def byte_decode(message):
    message = str(message)
    return (message[2:][:len(message)-3])

def input_thread_func():
    global sever_sending_data
    while True:
        for x in range(random.randint(2,3)):
            sever_sending_data[0][random.randint(0,5)] = random.randint(-9,99)
        for usr_update_DATA in sever_sending_data[0]:
            other_usr_data[client_ID][usr_update_DATA] = sever_sending_data[0][usr_update_DATA]
        time.sleep(2)


input_thread = threading.Thread(target=input_thread_func)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.settimeout(10)
    s.connect((HOST, 60000)) #PORT
    s.sendall(bytes(json.dumps(usrname),encoding="utf-8"))
    free_port = int.from_bytes(s.recv(1024), 'little', signed=False)
    print("Going to connect to free port:", free_port)

print("going to actuall connection")

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.settimeout(10)
    s.connect((HOST, free_port))
    update_data = json.loads(s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
    for usr_ID in update_data[0]: #makes sure ID's are int's
        other_usr_data[int(usr_ID)] = update_data[0][usr_ID]
    client_ID = update_data[1]
    other_usr_data[client_ID] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    del update_data
    input_thread.start()
    while True:
        sever_sending_data.append(message_ID)
        s.send(bytes(json.dumps(sever_sending_data),encoding="utf-8"))
        print("sever sending data:",sever_sending_data)
        sever_sending_data = [{},[]]
        data = json.loads(s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
        message_ID = data[2]
        print(message_ID,"Recived:", data)
        print(message_ID,other_usr_data)
        for NOTIF in data[1]:
            if NOTIF[0] == "J":
                print(NOTIF[1], "Joined ID:", NOTIF[2])
                other_usr_data[NOTIF[2]] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
            if NOTIF[0] == "D":
                print(NOTIF[1], "Disconnected ID:", NOTIF[2])
                del other_usr_data[NOTIF[2]]
            if NOTIF[0] == "E":
                print(NOTIF[1], "Errored out ID:", NOTIF[2], "Error:", NOTIF[3])
                del other_usr_data[NOTIF[2]]
        for other_usr_ID in data[0]:
            for usr_update_DATA in data[0][other_usr_ID]:
                other_usr_data[int(other_usr_ID)][int(usr_update_DATA)] = data[0][other_usr_ID][usr_update_DATA]
        time.sleep(delay)
    s.sendall(bytes("Disconnecting",encoding="utf-8"))
    data = s.recv(1024)
```

I have tried running it on a local network, and that seemed to work but only on an external port does it not work.

Comment: Your server should listen to `0.0.0.0` (all addresses). Localhost loops back inside the server.

Comment: What do you mean by Local host looping back inside the server?

Comment: Typically, localhost is assign to `127.0.0.1`, and any packet sent to any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` network will immediately loop back inside the host. No packets with an address in that range are to be seen on any network, anywhere. Loopback addresses are useful to test, but they cannot be used on a real network.

Comment: so should I use: HOST = "0.0.0.0"